# Specifying the directory for Select-Object

Tags: powershell

This is fairly straghtforward, so apologies!

I have a line of code which gets a $filename which it then uses to find matching files with different extensions:

```
$extractedFile = Get-Item -Path "$fileName*" | Where-Object -Property Extension -Match -Value 'CUE|BIN' | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty FullName
```

This works, however I recently changed the directory of where these files are. Currently the line above is looking for the files where the script is run from. How can I modify that line to look for the files in a different directory?

Many thanks!

Comment: `Get-Item -Path "X:\folder\$fileName*"` ?

Comment: Got it, I used Set-Location -Path C:/MyDir - although I wish there was a way to do that within the line above :-/

Answer (score 0):

> Currently the line above is looking for the files where the script is run from. How can I modify that line to look for the files in a different directory?

I'd suggest creating parameters to a function (or your overall script) that will point you at where the root directory *should* be:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $PSItem.FullName -PathType Container})]
    [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
    $Folder
)
```

Then you would change how you call your script:

```
.\MyFile.ps1 -Folder 'X:\Folder'
```